# Is this interview approach a good methodology for dialect fieldwork?

Tags: sociolinguistics, accent, field-linguistics

**How do I design a language survey of a local dialect?**

## Intro

I’m a rising high school senior who has been very interested in linguistics for the past few years.

I live in a mid-size U.S. city known for its cross-cultural roots.

My and most people of my parents’ generation speak with a [General American accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American_English).

My grandparents and their friends have an accent that is unique to the area.

I want to conduct a research project about this dialect.

## Research

I’ve identified 3 rough goals of my project:

1. to preserve this accent as a valuable resource for linguistic study
2. to analyze what distinguishes it from other dialects in similar parts of the country
3. to celebrate this endangered gem for its individuality and beauty

**My plan is to hold filmed interviews where I ask questions about the subjects’ upbringing and other influences.**

I would like to have each interviewee speak extemporaneously, in addition to reading a “standard paragraph” for a uniform comparison.

I’ll start with my grandparents, and then ask them to refer someone else to be interviewed.

## Guidelines and reference materials

I’d love feedback on any parts of this plan.

- Is this interview approach a good methodology for dialect fieldwork?
- What are considered some best practices?

**I’m asking for resources regarding best or standard practices for designing this kind of language survey:**

- what equipment I’ll need
- what data I should record
- can smartphones be used?
- the cost of this kind of experimental design
- what “standard paragraph” is suitable?

(I know I’m using accent and dialect interchangeably, but I understand there are likely differences.)

Comment: Depending on your location, local libraries sometimes have higher-quality microphones available for borrowing.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't really do research advice here, this is borderline off-topic. Please consult your supervisor for their advice.

Comment: I disagree that this is off topic, but it would be helpful if you could narrow it down a bit and ask a specific question, instead of asking for feedback in general. Audio equipment could be a good question, but then I would separate it from the rest of the question, and possibly ask other, focused questions on other topics.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a phenomenal project! I don't have tech-equipment types of advice for you, but if you need someone to bounce ideas off of further along in your project, let me know!

Audio quality is important, but I would guess that almost anything we have available today is a big improvement over the audio recordings that I was listening to in grad school! My professor had old recordings of interviews that she had conducted with speakers of a Peruvian Highlands dialect of Spanish using an old-school cassette recorder. I mostly remember that there was a good bit of background noise that I had to contend with, so I would say that the location for the interviews might be more important. Do a test recording before you start because even "little" sounds such as a fan or the AC in the background can sometimes get amplified in a recording.

Comment: And I would add: Try to record in a quiet room, preferably one with carpeting - if you can, drape thick blankets on the walls to absorb any echo.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of ethics: Ask the participants for permission to publish the recordings and document these permissions. Recordings gained without permission nowadays are close to useless, because you cannot publish them, nor share them with other researchers.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a great project. As someone who regularly records conversation and is assembling a corpus of conversation, I agree with those who said you can get good quality recordings adjusting your practices without fancy equipment.

In general, I would recommend recording in a room that has no empty walls. Any sort of textile helps. In the past, I have done things like bringing cushions and blankets to recording sessions, placing coats on chairs, and sitting on sofas. Sit away from fridges, ACs, TVs. You might not hear the noise, but your mics will likely pick it up. If you have the possibility of choosing the place for the interviews, choose a place you know, go there beforehand and try recording yourself. Adjust the environment as much as you need to get a clear sound and than take pictures to document how you moved things around (if you had to) so that you can recreate the situation for every speaker.

That said: one of the audio recording devices we use with my team is [this one](https://zoomcorp.com/en/us/handheld-recorders/handheld-recorders/h4n-pro/) by Zoom. You can get something less fancy than this, the important element, in my opinion, is the positioning of the microphones in a X shape. The position and polar pattern of the mics is good for the interview portion of your data collection phase. Place the recording between you and the participant with one mic pointing in the direction of each person.

With my team, we recorded conversations on the platform Zoom where people were using headsets and the quality of the sound captured by their mic was quite good. If you have a good headset at home, you could ask people to wear it and read in the mic.

But I also want to stress again: unless you need to do some specific analysis using sensitive software, your phone's mic and a pair of headphones with a mic is probably good enough. We recorded conversations with phones in the middle of the table and, while there are some forms of phonetic analysis that you cannot do with those data, the quality is good enough for analysis of dialectal variation (I have some colleagues working on it at the moment).

If you want to know more about microphones in general, another thing I recommend is to look into the concept of microphones polar patterns. [Here](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/what-are-microphone-polar-patterns/) is a blog describing what a microphone polar pattern is. Depending on the pattern of your mic, you are able to pick up sounds in different parts of your environment. In case you think the project has specific needs, this is a good starting point to identify them.

And finally, I am going to end with an advice that would have saved me hours of headache: if you film and record someone on two separate devices (e.g. camera and computer with headset mic), after you start recording, clap your hands once on camera. This will give you an easily recognizable point where to link your audio track to the video later on.

Good luck with your project and have fun with the data collection!